# Do I have to override all math operators in a subclass?

Tags: python

I want to make a simple Point2d class in a Python 3.7 program that implements just a few features. I saw in an SO answer (that I can't find now) that one way to create a Point class was to override `complex` so I wrote this:

```
import math

class Point2d(complex):

    def distanceTo(self, otherPoint):
        return math.sqrt((self.real - otherPoint.real)**2 + (self.imag - otherPoint.imag)**2)

    def x(self):
        return self.real

    def y(self):
        return self.imag
```

This works:

```
In [48]: p1 = Point2d(3, 3)

In [49]: p2 = Point2d(6, 7)

In [50]: p1.distanceTo(p2)
Out[50]: 5.0
```

But when I do this, `p3` is instance of `complex`, not `Point2d`:

```
In [51]: p3 = p1 + p2

In [52]: p3.distanceTo(p1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-37fbadb3015e> in <module>
----> 1 p3.distanceTo(p1)

AttributeError: 'complex' object has no attribute 'distanceTo'
```

Most of my background is in Objective-C and C# so I'm still trying to figure out the pythonic way of doing things like this. Do I need to override all the math operators I want to use on my Point2d class? Or am I going about this completely the wrong way?

Comment: You'll certainly have to override methods than create new instances if you want those new instances to be of your custom class. FWIW it seems like the problem is that just subclassing complex because it can hold two values is the root of your problem.

Comment: Why are you subclassing complex to begin with?

Comment: I'm subclassing complex because I want to inherit the things it already knows how to do. I wish I could find the answer that subclassed complex to make a Point class. I thought it seemed fairly elegant. So should I abandon that approach and just create a class from scratch that implements all the functionality I wanted to inherit from complex?

Comment: What do you want to inherit?

Comment: It seems like you need to override almost everything you want to inherit, so you're not really gaining much by inheriting.

Comment: Subclassing is useful for classes that mostly modify the object in place. It's not really that good for classes where most operations return new instances of the class.

Comment: @Barmar "It's not really that good for classes where most operations return new instances of the class." seems to be the key as to why I shouldn't take this approach.

Comment: Yes, that was my point. Whether you subclass or not, you're going to have to implement all those operations in your class.

Comment: You might find reading the section titled [Implementing the arithmetic operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#implementing-the-arithmetic-operations) in the documentation worthwhile.

Comment: This looks funny, you can take a look to a module I am writing, I do pretty similar things.

https://github.com/ekiim/odeanimate/blob/release/odeanimate/vector.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I suggest to implement your class `Point2d` from scratch.

If you're lazy, take a look to some lib like sympy which includes a `Point` class and other geometry stuff https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/geometry/index.html

Comment: This ends up being easiest and most straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

The problem, is that your class, when it uses any of the data model functions belonging to complex It returns a complex, so you'll need to turn this in to your `Point2d` class

adding this method should do the trick

```
def __add__(self, b):
    return Point2d(super().__add__(b))
```

But still there should be a better way of doing it. But this is the way to dynamically wrap some Data Model (dunder) methods.

By the way, the distance function you can make it shorter something like this

```
def distanceTo(self, otherPoint):
    return abs(self - otherPoint)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to mention a way of overriding all the methods without manually writing each of them, but only because we are all [consenting adults](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-October/025932.html) here. I don't really recommend it, it is much clearer if you just override each and every operation. That said, you can write a class wrapper which inspects all the methods of the base class and converts the output to a point if it is a complex type.

```
import math
import inspect


def convert_to_base(cls):
    def decorate_func(name, method, base_cls):
        def method_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            obj = method(*args, **kwargs)
            return cls.convert(obj, base_cls) if isinstance(obj, base_cls) else obj
        return method_wrapper if name not in ('__init__', '__new__') else method
    for base_cls in cls.__bases__:
        for name, method in inspect.getmembers(base_cls, inspect.isroutine):  # Might want to change this filter
            setattr(cls, name, decorate_func(name, method, base_cls))
    return cls


@convert_to_base
class Point2d(complex):

    @classmethod
    def convert(cls, obj, base_cls):
        # Use base_cls if you need to know which base class to convert.
        return cls(obj.real, obj.imag)

    def distanceTo(self, otherPoint):
        return math.sqrt((self.real - otherPoint.real)**2 + (self.imag - otherPoint.imag)**2)

    def x(self):
        return self.real

    def y(self):
        return self.imag

p1 = Point2d(3, 3)
p2 = Point2d(6, 7)
p3 = p1 + p2
p4 = p3.distanceTo(p1)
print(p4)

# 9.219544457292887
```

What is happening here is that it just checks all the methods of the base class, and if what it returns is of the type of the base class, converts it to the child class, as defined by the special classmethod in the child class.

Answer (score 0):

In general, prefer composition to inheritance. You can implement all the desired operations in terms of complex numbers.

```
class Point2D:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self._p = complex(x,y)

    @classmethod
    def _from_complex(self, z):
        return Point2D(z.real, z.imag)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Point2D._from_complex(self._p + other._p)

    # etc
```

Is it a lot of boilerplate? Yes. But it's not really boilerplate you can avoid.

Comment: Actually, you can avoid this kind of boilerplate in python.

Comment: Well, yes, with more compact, less readable boilerplate. I'm not advocating its use.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are interested in this. A while ago I started working in a module called `odeanimate` (For time reason the development is kind of stalled).

The idea was to create a module do to math in an explicit way, such that you have objects that respect the operators in a meaningful way.

I would encourage you to check this file in particular
[`odeanimate/vector.py`](https://github.com/ekiim/odeanimate/blob/release/odeanimate/vector.py), which in my opinion is a good example on how to override the operators.

But essentially the answer is to implement all the [*data model methods or dunder methods*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html), which the other answers already explained.